# Woocommerce change order recieved page title

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, hook-woocommerce

I am trying to change/add in the title of the "Order Recieved" Woocommerce page.

The below snippet works -  I am able to change the pre-existing **TEXT** with the following code:

```
    add_filter('woocommerce_thankyou_order_received_text', 'woo_change_order_received_text', 10, 2 );
function woo_change_order_received_text( $str, $order ) {
    $new_str = $str . ' We have emailed the purchase receipt to you.';
    return $new_str;
}
```

The below snippet does not work. -  I am unable to change/add the **TITLE** and also pass in the username to personalise it. Here is the code and also an image of the output I am trying to achieve....The **"You are awesome FIRSTNAME"** added in.

```
    <?php
add_filter( 'the_title', 'woo_personalize_order_received_title', 10, 2 );
function woo_personalize_order_received_title( $title, $id ) {
    if ( is_order_received_page() && get_the_ID() === $id ) {
        global $wp;
        // Get the order. Line 9 to 17 are present in order_received() in includes/shortcodes/class-wc-shortcode-checkout.php file
        $order_id  = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_thankyou_order_id', absint( $wp->query_vars['order-received'] ) );
        $order_key = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_thankyou_order_key', empty( $_GET['key'] ) ? '' : wc_clean( $_GET['key'] ) );
        if ( $order_id > 0 ) {
            $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
            if ( $order->get_order_key() != $order_key ) {
                $order = false;
            }
        }
        if ( isset ( $order ) ) {
            //$title = sprintf( "You are awesome, %s!", esc_html( $order->billing_first_name ) ); // use this for WooCommerce versions older then v2.7
        $title = sprintf( "You are awesome, %s!", esc_html( $order->get_billing_first_name() ) );
        }
    }
    return $title;
}
```

[image]

This should be possible as there are examples on how to do it, such as [here](https://www.tychesoftwares.com/how-to-customize-the-woocommerce-thank-you-page/)...I just can't figure out why the main title wont even appear?

Comment: your code should work fine actually i just test it on my location and it's fine, if am in your position i will start first to increase the priority, and if it didn't work check your condition one by one

Comment: @kashalo - So e.g. (10,3)?...it is strange because the changing of the text worked at same priority of (10,2)

Comment: no (20, 2) the first param is the priority second is for how many accepted_args your filter  should have

Comment: this is different filter so it's not neccassry to have same priority for each filter  https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_filter/

Comment: @kashalo I tried adjusting the priority to (20,2), but still no luck - really confused as to why it's not working

Comment: did you tried to remove the condition and just return custom  title?

Comment: @kashalo Yes I just tried that now, still didn't work. It's not even triggering the title for me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178701/discussion-between-kashalo-and-giuls).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a workaround I inspected the CSS and changed the text below the header to be a larger size and the font family required.

Then through the below PHP I created the custom text with the customer name in the header.

```
    add_filter('woocommerce_thankyou_order_received_text', 'woo_change_order_received_text', 10, 2 );
function woo_change_order_received_text( $str, $order ) {
    $new_str = sprintf( "You are awesome, %s :) - We've recieved your order.", esc_html( $order->get_billing_first_name() ) );
    return $new_str;
}
```

Comment: For anyone looking at how to do this, I stumbled across this article whilst trying to figure out how to change the title too. https://rudrastyh.com/woocommerce/thank-you-page.html. 'woocommerce_endpoint_order-received_title' is the best hook for changing the main title on the page.

Answer (score 0):

2022 update:

```
function ps_title_order_received( $title, $id ) {
    if ( is_order_received_page() && get_the_ID() === $id ) {
        global $wp;

        $order_id  = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_thankyou_order_id', absint( $wp->query_vars['order-received'] ) );
        $order_key = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_thankyou_order_key', empty( $_GET['key'] ) ? '' : wc_clean( $_GET['key'] ) );

        if ( $order_id > 0 ) {
            $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
            if ( $order->get_order_key() != $order_key ) {
                unset( $order );
            }
        }

        if ( isset ( $order ) ) {
            $title = sprintf( "Thank you, %s!", esc_html( $order->get_billing_first_name() ) );
        }
    }

    return $title;
}
add_filter( 'the_title', 'ps_title_order_received', 10, 2 );
```